# Clear array every time it is called

Tags: ios, swift

I have an array with chart data and I call it in 3 functions. But this functions are called when user click on segmented control, so it can be called multiple time. I wonder if exists better way to clear array every time when it is called, than just do it manually like: array = []. I need to use same array in multiple places and every time when it is called it needs to be clear.

```
var array = [ChartData]()

func firstFunction() {
 array = []
.
.
.
}

func secondFunction() {
 array = []
.
.
.
}

func thirdFunction() {
 array = []
.
.
.
}
```

I have tried to do it with computed property but it doesn't work.

```
var array: [ChartData] {
  didSet {
   array.removeAll()
}
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to remove all of the elements from the array? How do you add the data to the array?  Do you `append`elements?  Why not just create a new, local, array variable in the function and simply assign it to `self.array` at the end?

Comment: Maybe you want `willSet` instead of `didSet`?

Comment: I need to remove all of the elements from the array, because its data sets for the chart. User can select period of time (week/month/year) so current chart data sets needs to clear and set accordingly to selected period of time. I have thought about creating local array variable but I wonder if cleaner way is just create one array and clear it every time